# Ambiguous reference to member jsonobject with options Error with Parse Cloud Code Response

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parse-platform

When i doing Parse Cloud function with Parse iOS SDK Swift 3

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "callFromApp", withParameters: ["Hello" : "Boy"]) { (obj:Any?, error:Error?)->Void in
            let jsonObject = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: obj! as! JSONObject, options: .allowFragments)
}
```

Im getting error Ambiguous reference to member jsonObject with options.

Comment: How is JSONObject defined?

Comment: `typealias JSONObject = [String:Any]`

Comment: can you please print obj for me please.

Comment: `{ "bye" = { some nested obects... } }`